# Limit over a base

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Reading [this book](http://instructor.sdu.edu.kz/~verbovskiy/Math%20Analysis%201/Zorich1_en.pdf) (pg. 129) i found this definition about The limit of a Function over a Base

> **Definition**: Let $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ R be a function defined on a set $X$ and $\mathcal{B}$ a base in $X$. A number  $A\in \mathbb{R}$ is called the *limit of the function $f$ over the base $\mathcal{B}$*  if for every neighborhood $V(A)$ of A,  there is an element $B\in \mathcal{B}$  whose image $f(B)\subset V(A)$.
>   In logical symbols:
>   $\lim_{\mathcal{B}} f(x)=A:= $ for all $V(A) \exists B\in \mathcal{B}(f(B)\subset V(A))$

I was thinking that this concept is more useful in the application part as it is the composition of functions to be able to relate different bases for example natural and real as in the example 20 (pg.134). My question is: Why is it necessary to use this new definition or why extend to it? could not solve that example 20 with the composition of functions that we know in $\mathbb{R}$?

Or in general, why is it necessary to extend the definition of limit on a basis? Any help with last question, thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say "extend", you imply that there is some other less "extended" definition of the limit of a function over a base. What is it? Can you edit it into the question and explain how the definition on page 129 is an extension of your other definition?

Comment: I want to know if the new definition is an extension of the definition we know of limit or is it another way to represent it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The motivation for this particular form of the definition of a limit is given on the very next page:

> Earlier  we considered  examples  of the  bases most  often  used  in analysis. In  a  specific  problem  in  which  one  or  another  of these  bases  arises,  one  must  know  how  to  decode  the  general  definition  and  write  it  in  the  form  specific  to  that  base.

There then follows a few of the definitions of various kinds of limits in single-variable real analysis. We have limits 
for $x$ tending to a finite number $a \in \mathbb R$;
$x$ tending to finite $a$ but only from below;
$x$ tending to finite $a$ but only from above;
$x$ tending to $+\infty$; and $x$ tending to $-\infty$.
And then for each of those ways $x$ can tend, the limit of $f(x)$ might be a finite number $A \in \mathbb R$, or it might be $+\infty$; or it might be $-\infty.$
That's already fifteen different ways to take a limit.

On page 107 you were first introduced to the definition of a limit,
$$ \forall \epsilon > 0\; \exists \delta > 0\; \forall x \in E\; (0 < \lvert x - a\rvert < \delta \implies \lvert f(x) - A\rvert < \epsilon).$$

This defines the limit when $x$ tends to $a$ and the limit is a finite number 
$A \in \mathbb R.$
Now for each of the other fourteen limits we have to go fiddling with various parts of this definition, replacing some expressions with different expressions in order to have a correct definition of each limit.

So the motivation here is that the only thing you have to do differently for each limit is define what the base is (depending on what $x$ is tending to, and how)
and what the neighborhoods of $A$ are, and then you have your formula defining a limit, always the same formula with no further changes.

I wouldn't call this an extension of any of the other fifteen definitions of a limit, because (as you observed) at this point there hasn't been any attempt to define any limit that was not already defined.
Rather I would call it a kind of generalization of the definition of a limit,
in particular, at this point it's the kind of generalization where you take a lot of related but all-slightly-different definitions and replace them with a single definition.

You *could* go even further and define bases over sets other than $\mathbb R$ and subsets of $\mathbb R$; for example, you could define a base in a multidimensional Euclidean space. And that would be a different kind of generalization of the limits you already know. Or perhaps you could call it an extension to a different domain.
I don't see anything like that in the pages surrounding the definition, however.

Comment: One last doubt, to solve example 20, then I can use the composition of ususal functions but modifying it for x tends to infinity, or could I use the Sequential Criterion for a Limit of a Function, which one would suit me? it would be without using the composition limit on a base, thanks for explanation.