# Sequence convergence to limit point definition

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence

I have been thinking that the definition why the Convergence condition of a sequence on to a limit point(s) is very rigid. The definition is set of points on a Topological space $(X, \mathcal{T})$  $(x_1,x_2...x_n)$ converges to a Limit $L$, then we require ALL the points after some $n \ge N, N\in \mathbb{N}$ s.t $x_n, x_n+1, \cdots$ are in ALL neighborhoods of $L$. My question is as follows. What if we relax that condition and say "atleast" one point $x_k$ shows up in ALL neighborhood of $L$ after $n \ge N$. This allows some divergent series like $1, -1, 1, -1, \cdots$ to be convergent on both $1$ and $-1$..is there a logical reasoning that requires all the points after $n$? Note that the newer definition leaves the convergent condition as it is. Possibly, allows some divergent series to be termed convergent...In addition, we can possibly add something like $x_{k+1}$ must occur in atleast a neighborhood $N_{k+1}$, s.t, $N_{k+1} \subset N_{k}$. i.e capture the "closeness" to L ..

Comment: Taking look on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3420963/limit-over-a-base may be interesting.

Comment: Well, this basically just confuses convergence and limit points. Why would it be advantageous to redefine convergence to something weaker if we already have that notion in the theory of limit points?

Comment: Just want to understand the motivation behind that in-vogue definition. Was there some field problem where the current defition was forced ? or the new weaker definition would fail?  etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is close to what's usually called a *cluster point* of a sequence $(x_n)_n$:

> $p$ is a cluster point of $(x_n)_n$ iff for every neighbourhood $O$ of $p$ and every $N \in \Bbb N$ there is some $m \ge N$ such that $x_m \in O$.

So every neighbourhood of $p$ contains infnitely many terms from the sequence, but not necessarily a tail of the sequence. So your sequence $1,-1,1,-1,\ldots$ has no limit but two cluster points $1$  and $-1$.

In a metric space (or more generally a first countable space) this implies that there is a subsequence $(x_{n_k})_k$ that converges to $p$, but this need not be the case in a general space. Cluster points aren't used very much, but they are studied in some contexts.

I think limits (unique in Hausdorff spaces) and cluster points will do nicely to describe behaviour of points wrt sequences.

Comment: Thanks for the answer...Is there any concept that captures the closeness of a particular neighborhood of p vs Other fanned-out neighborhoods of p?